# Python: Use backquotes in command given to subprocess.Popen function

Tags: python, python-3.x, subprocess

I am trying to execute, from a python3 script, Unix commands that looks like that:

```
mycommand `cmd_giving_a_path`/file
```

So I am using the subprocess.Popen function. But whatever I tried, the subprocess doesn't evaluate the command between backquotes.
Here is what I tried:

```
>>> subprocess.Popen(['echo', 'toto'])
<subprocess.Popen object at 0x2a98df1c50>
>>> toto
```

Fine!

```
subprocess.Popen(['echo', 'toto', '`ls`'])
<subprocess.Popen object at 0x2a98df1d50>
>>> toto `ls`
```

Fine too!

```
>>> subprocess.Popen(['echo', 'toto', '`ls`'], shell=True)
<subprocess.Popen object at 0x2a98df1d90>
```

I don't understand this one: I have no output at all.
With this command I expected that a shell is spawned and receive the command:

```
echo toto `ls`
```

But obsviously, I am wrong!

Could someone help with that?

Thank you!

PS: For those who may ask 'why do you need this?' the answer is: 
because the options for the commands are read from an input file that may contains this kind of syntax.

Comment: What *else* is in the input file?

Comment: I am not sure to understand what you mean? Are you talking about environment variables and things like that?

Comment: I mean, if the input file **only** contains this stuff, then why are you trying to "interpret" it from python instead of just running it as a Bash script or whatever?

Comment: In fact, I am trying to implement a configurable compile script.
I need to compile sources for different tools and with different sets of options. So I have a file containing lines like that: `tool1 set1 : -options...`
Depending on which tool and options is selected by the user, I extract the
corresponding options and give it to the selected tool. The file list is stored in
another file that is parsed too. I could use a Makefile, but I don't know how to write good ones and I prefer Python command line parser. Do you think my approach is bad?

Comment: There is already a fairly standard Python compile-script utility: [SCons](http://www.scons.org/).

Comment: Thanks for the link. It's a shame I have no time to look at it right now and use it in my project! I'll try this when I'll have enough time. Even if my script is better than the previous one I made in bash, it is still not flexible enough... Thanks again!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the pydoc documentation for subprocess: *On UNIX, with shell=True: If args is a string, it specifies the command string to execute through the shell.  If args is a sequence, the first item specifies the command string, and **any additional items will be treated as additional shell arguments**.*

I.e., you were telling subprocess to run the following command:

```
bash -c 'echo' 'toto' '`ls`'
```

As ephemient pointed out, what you really want to run is:

```
bash -c 'echo toto `ls`'
```

which you can do with either of:

```
subprocess.Popen('echo toto `ls`', shell=True)
subprocess.Popen(['echo toto `ls`'], shell=True)
```

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation. I am new to python and I was totally confused with the possibilities offered by the Popen function. Thanks to you it's much more clear now!

Answer (score 3):

Works as expected:

```
subprocess.Popen('echo toto `ls`', shell=True)
```

Comment: Thanks to you too. Even if it wasn't as detailed as the other answer, I understood what is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with the way you are going about this but could you use fabric?

Link: http://docs.fabfile.org/en/1.4.0/index.html

I think it would be simple to write a function that reads from the file and executes those commands using fabric.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But I knew I was possible to do what I wanted to with the standard lib. Moreover I prefer not to install new packages to reduces the dependencies!